# Simple form validation over multiple divs

Tags: javascript, forms, button, if-statement

I have a contact form that has 3 steps, each has its own "tab" which is then submitted via an email php script. Live version is at http://agoodman.com.au/wptest/menswear-porter-service/ (click "BOOK IN 60 SECONDS").

In the first form, I want to ensure that they've entered an email address before proceeding. I've attempted this via the following:

```
<button class="btn classic" onclick=" if ('#basicdetails .email').value ='=' ' '){return false;} else {document.getelementbyid('n.2').click();}">next</button>
```

At present the code does indeed check for an email address and halts if nothing has been entered, but when an email IS entered the form doesn't progress. ('#n.2' is a tab that simply shows the next page of the form). If I remove the `if` statement and just make the button code:

`<button class="btn classic" onclick="document.getelementbyid('n.2').click()">next</button>`

then the form progresses as it should, but obviously doesn't halt when an email address isn't entered.

Is my `if/else' syntax wrong? Otherwise, what am I missing here?

**EDIT:**

Made some big errors with syntax (first try with this sort of thing), see updated code:

```
<button class="btn classic" id="firstTab">next</button>

<script>
$('.btn#firstTab').click(function(){
if (('#basicdetails .email').value =='') {
  return false;
} else {
 $('#n2').click();
}
});

</script>
```

Comment: You may want to checkout this plugin, it will _greatly_ simplify the process. http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/.

Comment: That is quite helpful indeed. I'll probably end up using it, but for my own education I'd still like to know what I did wrong in the code above!

Comment: Check my answer hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Using inline JavaScript is never a good idea. If you separate your markup from your logic you'll be able to organize it better and spot errors easily. You'll see the problem right away if you break your code down and indent it properly:

```
if ('#basicdetails .email').value ='=' ' ') {
  return false;
} else {
  document.getelementbyid('n.2').click();
}
```

A few problems indeed. You're missing a `(` in your `if` statement. Then you *need* to use a comparison operator, such as `==` or `===`. The `=` operator is *just* for assignment. And finally you can tell that this `='=' ' '` looks like a mess, it's not at all obvious what that means, plus is not valid JavaScript. Also if `('#basicdetails .email')` was meant to be a jQuery selector you're missing the `$` before the parenthesis.

Comment: Yes indeed, lots of errors there. I'll amend the post above with updated code, as it's still not working.